# Average 3D paths

Tags: r, math, graphics, 3d, average

I have two paths in 3D and I want to "average" them, if there's such a thing.

I have the xyz pairs timestamped at the time they were sampled:

```
    ms   x   y   z
    3   0.1 0.2 0.6
    12  0.1 0.2 1.3
    23  2.1 4.2 0.3
    55  0.1 6.2 0.3
```

Facts about the paths:

- They all start and end on/near the same xyz point.
- I have the total duration it took to complete the path as well as individual vertices
- They have different lengths (i.e. different number of xyz pairs).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: PS I am trying to do all this in R :/

Comment: What do you mean with averaging them ? To get a center of mass, to smooth them, or to interpolate them to other time values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @6502's answer.

If you wish to retrieve a list of points that would make up the average path, you could sample the `avg` function at the instances of the individual input points. (Stretched toward the average length)

```
def avg2(T1, waypoints1, T2, waypoints2):
    # Collect the times we want to sample at
    T = (T1 + T2) / 2
    times = []
    times.extend(t*T/T1 for (t,x,y) in waypoints1)  # Shift the time towards
    times.extend(t*T/T2 for (t,x,y) in waypoints2)  #   the average
    times.sort()

    result = []
    last_t = None
    for t in times:
        # Check if we have two points in close succession
        if last_t is not None and last_t + 1.0e-6 >= t:
            continue
        last_t = t

        # Sample the average path at this instance
        x, y = avg(t, T1, waypoints1, T2, waypoints2)
        yield t, x, y
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple method is the following...

First build a function `interp(t, T, waypoints)` that given the current time `t`, the total path duration `T` and the path `waypoints` returns the current position. This can be done using linear interpolation or more sophisticated approaches to avoid speed or acceleration discontinuities.

Once you have `interp` the average path can be defined as (example in python)

```
def avg(t, T1, waypoints1, T2, waypoints2):
    T = (T1 + T2) / 2
    return middlePoint(interp(t*T1/T, T1, waypoints1),
                       interp(t*T2/T, T2, waypoints2))
```

the duration of the average path will be the average `T = (T1 + T2) / 2` of the two durations.

It's also easy to change this approach to make a weighted average path.

Answer (score 3):

In R, the distances between consecutive points in that series assuming it is in a dataframe named "dat"
 would be:

```
 with(dat, sqrt(diff(x)^2 +diff(y)^2 +diff(z)^2) )
#[1] 0.700000 4.582576 2.828427
```

There are a couple of averages I could think of average distance in interval, average distance traveled per unit time. Depends on what you want. This gives the average velocity in the three intervals:

```
 with(dat, sqrt(diff(x)^2 +diff(y)^2 +diff(z)^2) /diff(ms) )
#[1] 0.07777778 0.41659779 0.08838835
```

Answer (score 2):

There is definitely such a thing.  For each point on path A, find the point that correponds to your current point on path B, and then find the mid-point between those corresponding verticies.  You will then get a path in-between the two that is the "average" of the two paths.  If you have a mis-match where you did not sample the two paths the same, then for an interior point on path A (i.e., not the end-point), find the two closest sampled points with a similar time-sampling on path B, and locate the mid-point of the triangle those three points will make.

Now since you've discreetized your path by sampling it, this "average" is only going to be an approximation, not a "true" average like you could do by solving for the average function between two differentiable parametric functions defined by `r(t) = <x(t), y(t), z(t)>`.